# Отклонение приложения в App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple, appstore

Здравствуйте.

У меня проблема с опубликованием приложения в App Store, приложение не прошло модерацию. Приложение предназначено в первую очередь для клиентов нашей компании, а это около 60 000 человек (у нас энергетическая компания, снабжающая энергоресурсами область). В приложении используется авторизация, после чего клиент попадает в личный кабинет, где может просмотреть всю информацию, начисление и оплату по своей квартире.

В письме указана следующая причина:

Guideline 3.2 - Business
We found that your app is not appropriate for the World storefront because it is a custom app designed specifically for your company, whose users are in Kazakhstan.
At this time, Kazakhstan is not part of the Volume Purchase Program.
Next Steps
Please revise your app to set the storefront to Kazakhstan.

Что можно предпринять, чтобы приложение одобрили?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как вариант попробуйте страну распространения поставить только Казахстан. В itunesconnect -> Ценообразование и доступность -> Доступность

Answer (score 0):

Для распространения приложения внутри компании Вам нужно Enterprise Program. Таким образом приложение будет доступно только для закрытого круга людей. Больше информации [тут](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).